# Discrepancies between AU and BP values in HCA

Tags: r, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I conducted a hierarchical cluster analysis in *R* on a pool of 20 words that have certain common traits. I used hclust(). After, I did multiscale bootstrap resampling using pvclust(). While smaller-level clusters have very similar or even the same AU and BP values, the more the cluster becomes general (the more subclusters it encompasses, e.g. the higher number it has), the bigger the difference between AU and BP values (for example, 92:21 and 79:6). I was wondering how to explain that?

Comment: If you want to get good answers, it's helpful to define acronyms the first time they appear (HCA, AU, BP).